# Delete the database without single-use it

Tags: sql-server-2019

I get an error when I try to delete a database with the following command.

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS NewDB
```

****Error**: Msg 3702, Level 16, State 4, Line 1
Cannot drop database "NewDB" because it is currently in use.**

---

I must move the database to single user mode so that I can delete it.

```
IF DB_ID('NewDB') > 0
    BEGIN
    ALTER DATABASE NewDB SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
    DROP DATABASE NewDB
    END
GO
```

Before deleting this database I need to identify which sessions are connected to this database that prevents it from being deleted.

Comment: Do you mean "what sessions are **now** connected to this database"?

Comment: yes, I want to see exactly what session is connected to this database that prevents it from being deleted.